# html email outlook 2003 issue

Tags: html, css, outlook-2003

I have an html email set up as

```
<td valign="top"><table width="650" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="25"  valign="top">
                <img src="/images/left_border.jpg" border="0" align="right" style="padding:0; display: block;">
            </td>
            <td width="600"  valign="top" style="padding: 0px;">
                <img src="/images/banner.jpg" border="0" align="left" style="padding:0; display: block;">
          </td>
            <td width="25" align="left">
                <img src="/images/right_border.jpg" border="0" align="left" style="padding:0; display: block;">
            </td>   
        </tr>
                 </table>
              </td>
```

However in outlook 2003 and entourage email clients, it appears as an additional border on left and right sides.

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Not sure what you mean without a screenshot but have you tried `<table border="0">`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work well in Outlook 2007+ either because you're using non-compatible tags including `padding:` and `display:`.  So, back to the drawing board all around.  Here's a refresher on what the various browsers support:  http://www.campaignmonitor.com/downloads/documents-tools/Campaign_Monitor_Guide_to_CSS_Support_in_Email_27_Aug_2009.pdf

Technically, the code you posted is invalid because it starts with a `<td>` which has to be inside a `<table>` and `<tr>` to be valid.  I'm suspecting you posted just a snippet, so perhaps providing the entire context would be best.